# Jetty Server started but can't access it on browser

Tags: java, jetty, localhost, maven-jetty-plugin

I tried to run a Java web application using Jetty Server. The Jetty Server is running as shown on the cmd, but while I tried to access `localhost:10000` via browser (Chrome, IE or Mozilla Firefox), the browser always ends up on googles the address (`Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:10000`).

The tutorial is based on [this](https://github.com/endymuhardin/belajar-restful) link. I also tried to setting the proxy server by adding `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` on the exceptions, but still the same. What's wrong? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That is because the you should go to port 8080

```
http://localhost:8080
```

It says so in the screen shot, Started ... @0.0.0.0:8080

Comment: No, still can't access the localhost.